# How to define disable dates on DateField?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

> ### **Scenario**
>
> ---
>
> I have a [DateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.1/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html) for users to search old auction informations. But old auction informations can only search until yesterday. So , my  [DateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.1/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html) component will show yesterday date as default. Dates these were from today and later should be unselectable at my datefield.

To satisfy above conditions , I setted *[setRangeEnd()](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.1/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html#setRangeEnd%28java.util.Date%29)* as below

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date yesterday = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    PopupDateField auctionDate = new PopupDateField("Auction Date", yesterday);
    auctionDate.setStyleName("auctiondatebox");
    auctionDate.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    auctionDate.setRangeEnd(yesterday);
```

And I setted color of outside range days to red.

```
  .v-datefield-calendarpanel-day-outside-range {
    color:red !important;
  }
```

That's fine but I have still another condition. Every **Sunday** , auction was **OFF**. So , users shouldn't be selectable these off-days in my datefield (*every **Sundays** should unselectable and show color as red)*.
Please somebody give me suggestions how can I define unselectable dates in [DateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.1/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html). Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with css.
If Sunday is last column:

```
.v-datefield-calendarpanel-body  tr>td:last-child{
   pointer-events: none;
   color: red;
}
```

If Sunday column is first column (in vaadin datefield first column is hidden, therefore the Sunday column is the second):

```
.v-datefield-calendarpanel-body  tr>td:first-child + td{
   pointer-events: none;
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: I setted header (dayNames) to original color and days of previous these are also in **SUNDAY** to red as `.v-datefield-calendarpanel-body {
   .v-datefield-calendarpanel-weekdays .v-first {
      color : rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.85) !important;
   }
   tr>td:first-child + td{
      pointer-events: none;
      color: red;
      .v-datefield-calendarpanel-day-offmonth{
   color: red;
      }   
   }
};`